# Is my application of Boyce-Codd NF correct in this exercise?

Tags: database-design, bcnf

***EXAM*** revision, not homework.

I'm working on this exercise and I would like to check is my solution okay:

Given the following relationship, R, and set of functional dependencies, F: 
R = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I} 
F= { {C,D} -> {A}, 
{G} -> {E}, 
{C,D,E} -> {G,B,H}, 
{B} -> {F}, 
{H} -> {I} } 
decompose R into relations that satisfy Boyce-Codd normal form.

My answer: ***BOLD*** is primary key

(***C***,***D***,A)

(***C***,***D***,***E***,B,H)

(***B***,F)

(***H***,I)

(***G***,C,D)

(***E***,***G***)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first four you derived are all in 5NF.

- {**G** CD}
- {**EG**}

But these two don't look right.

For one thing, one of your FDs is G->E. In a relation that contains only G and E, how did you determine that the right decomposition is

- {**EG**}

instead of

- {**G** E}

given that the FD G->E still has to hold?

At a glance, I don't see how you can derive G->CD from the FDs you gave.

Comment: As per this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form `Achievability of BCNF` I was trying to capture: {AB → C, C → B}.
I've well and truly confused myself with this.

Comment: Thank you for getting involved @Mike
I'll try again, one of the rules I have is if `{X->Y}` violates BCNF, decompose `R` (all attributes) in to `{R-Y}` and `{XY}`. So I made `R={C,D,E,G}-{E} = {C,D,G}`  and my `X` is `{G}` and my `Y` is `{E}` so I get `{G,E}`. But in my original question I didn't show the correct composite primary keys so they should have been `{***C***,***D***,***G***}` and `{***G***,***E***}`. I really do hope I'm getting a handle on this or I'm in trouble :)   [can't bold in comments]

Comment: This is difficult in the comments box: take this relation R {studentID, Final, Advisor} and some entries {{1,IT,Smith},{1,ECON,Murphy},{2,ECON,Murphy},{3,IT,Smith}} and decompose to 2 tables:{{studentID,Final}->{Advisor},{Advisor}->{Final}}. As it stands if studentID=1 changed from ECON to BIOLOGY the advisor Murphy would now be pointing to the wrong Final. So to stop that from happening we must loose some functional dependency for correctness. Applying what I did in the previous comment helps this. The other way is to set triggers in your DB.

Comment: You didn't answer my question: Where did you learn that rule?  Your decomposition of R = {studentID, Final, Advisor} is wrong. Quick check: decomposition by projection *always* yields a relation with fewer attributes than you started with.

Comment: Sorry, my exams started and I had to focus. The solution I mention is from my lecturer.